# trouble uninstalling java on win7 machine

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to uninstall java through control panel-->uninstall, however when I run cmd and type java -version, I still obtain:

java -version

java version "1.7.0_07"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)

Java Hotspot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)

Thanks.

Comment: You said you uninstalled java6u45 so it is showing java 1.7 when you type java -version.

Comment: I uninstalled all the java and it still shows this.

Comment: So, what's the problem? You uninstalled java6u45 and now have java7.

Comment: sorry, wrong title. I should have written "uninstalling all java" on the system. Title edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open cmd

```
C:> for %i in (javac.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
```

If you have a JDK installed, the Path is displayed,
for example: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\javac.exe`

You can remove them.

And you have to remove JAVA related system variables by going here

```
Start -> Computer -> System Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> PATH.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check your path from the command line.
I have multiple JDKs and JREs installed and if needed (for an old application), I change my path.

Go to your command like, type `path` and hit enter.
Also, in order to see the JAVA_HOME, type `echo %JAVA_HOME%` in your command line.

Check exactly which version of java is still installed on your system.

Then find it in the control panel and remove it.

Please provide feedback. The more extreme solutions would be:

1. Try another uninstaller such as `revo uninstaller` (I am not affiliated with them).
2. Remove the directory, also the entries in your environmental variables (path, etc).

Option 2 is the last solution and not the best.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are having another java installed in your machine. Go to environment variable as said [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) then find out where your JAVA_HOME has been set and remove that installed java from your system.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the windows system and check again.
prior to restart remove JAVA_HOME and PATH variable from system environment variables.
if still the problem persists that mean you have jre left with  uninstalled. so,check properly and try to find it and uninstall it.